# Cannot reach list in other class in main class

Tags: c#

I have 2 files, one contains:

```
namespace Vluchten_Boeken    
{
     public class Vluchten
     {
         public string FlightNr;
         public string FlightCarrier;
         public string Destination;
         public int maxPassagers;
         public int bookedPassagers;

         public Vluchten(string _FlightNr, string _FlightCarrier, string _Destination, int _maxPassagers, int _bookedPassagers)
         {
             this.FlightNr = _FlightNr;
             this.FlightCarrier = _FlightCarrier;
             this.Destination = _Destination;
             this.maxPassagers = _maxPassagers;
             this.bookedPassagers = _bookedPassagers;     
         }
     } 
}
```

the other file contains:

```
namespace Vluchten_Boeken
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.Write("");

            foreach (Vluchten Vluchten in vluchtList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(vluchtList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I can easily do a `foreach` loop on the list in the same file that the list is in, but when I try to do it in the other file, I get

```
Error   1   The name 'vluchtList' does not exist in the current context
```

It's probably an easy fix and maybe I've been googling the wrong things but I can't work it out.

Comment: Google "variable scope"

Comment: Ive tried to set my list to public but that only gives me more errors..

Comment: You have never declared `vluchtList`. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Denn: You cannot reference properties of another class unless you have a reference to an *instance* of that class. Even in that case, you would refer to it as *classInstance*.vluchtList.

Comment: Although possible, I don't recommend having a variable with the same name of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that vluchtList has not been defined.

In your line "foreach (Vluchten Vluchten in vluchtList)", you are trying to access something called vluchtList that the compiler doesn't know about.

Before you can use vluchtList, you will need to define it.  It looks like it's supposed to be a list, so try this before the above line:

```
List<Vluchten> vluchtList = new List<Vluchten>();
```

This will define the variable to the type List, meaning a list of Vluchten objects.

While that's good, your foreach loop will not appear to do anything with it, because it is empty, so you will probably want to fill it with some Vluchten data:

```
vluchtList.Add(new Vluchten
{
    FlightNr = "My Flight Number";
    FlightCarrier = "My Flight Carrier";
    Destination = "My Destination";
    maxPassagers = 200;
    bookedPassagers = 130;
});
```

This is only adding one Vluchten object to the list, but you can add many.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to make this List public too, if I want to access it within another class?

Comment: No, the use of the public modifier only determines the visibility level of one class's properties to other classes.  So, for example, because your Vluchten class properties are public, any instance of the class you make within your Vluchten_Boeken class will be allowed to access them.

Answer (score 0):

3 problems:

1. Your list `vluchtList` is not defined anywhere. You have to define it and populate it with some `Vluchten` objects in order to output anything.
2. In your loop, you should use the current `vluchten` object from the list when doing your console output rather than outputting the whole `List<Vluchten>` each time
3. You should override the `ToString()` property on your class so that it outputs something meaningful. Without the override, `ToString()` (which is what will get called internally in `Console.WriteLine()`) will just spit out some information about the `Vluchten` type.

Here's a sample of code that should help here:

```
public class Vluchten
{
    // Existing code here . . .

    // Override the ToString() method
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
            "{0} flight #{1} is heading to {2} carrying {3} passengers out of {4} max.",
            FlightCarrier, FlightNr, Destination, bookedPassagers, maxPassagers);
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Normally this would be created and populated elsewhere.
    // I've put it here for now because it's simpler for this example
    var vluchtList = new List<Vluchten>
        {
            new Vluchten("flight1", "carrier1", "destination1", 10, 1),
            new Vluchten("flight2", "carrier2", "destination2", 20, 2),
            new Vluchten("flight3", "carrier1", "destination3", 30, 3),
            new Vluchten("flight4", "carrier2", "destination1", 40, 4),
            new Vluchten("flight5", "carrier1", "destination2", 50, 5),
        };

    Console.WriteLine("");

    // In the real app, where we aren't creating the list above, it's possible
    // that there may be no flights. So if the list is empty (or null) we can
    // tell the user that there is no info (rather than not outputting anything)
    if (vulchtList == null || !vluchtList.Any())
    {
         Console.WriteLine("There is no flight information to display.");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Vluchten vluchten in vluchtList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(vluchten);
        }
    }
}
```